# Is my server specification good for a database driven site

Tags: windows-server-2003

I have a dedicated server.its specifications are as follows
Intel xeon processor 2GH x 2,
3GB Ram,
500 GB Hard disk drive.
I am using SQL server 2008 r2 express as database
The website is developed in Visual studio 2010.
The server will also serve database to vb.net applications within the firewall.
Is it enough. Since i'am using sql server express edition however it will only consume 1 GB of ram. But for other operations is it enough.
I'am not expecting much traffic on my website.
i am using windows server 2003 as OS on my server. Also should I upgrade to Windows server 2008.

Comment: It's completely impossible to answer this question without any meaningful data about your workload.

Answer (score 2):

You tell me. I have a car, it has 2 seats, one steering wheel and four wheels. Is it good enough?

This is not meant sarcastic. The MOST critical part for database performance mostly is disc performance. You tell you ahve a 500gb hard disc - that is slow. Now whether this is good enough or not depends on what you do. "database driven site" is anything from my personal blog (hardly any readers) to twitter that uses a cluster of servers.

In general it is a not slow but outdated server with pathetic little RAM (3gb IS low for a server, especially given the price of RAM - I am just buying 32gb for a could of hundred USD) and a slow disc. If it is good enough it is good enough. If not it is not. Chances are it IS good enough, but that is all tending around your "I am not expecting much traffic" statement. Without stupid (and I mean utterly stupid) programming it should suffice. Example for stupid programming: we once had a forum where we showed the number of registered users at the bottom of every page. Due to - ah - programmer blackout - we pulled the hole user table every time and counted in memory. On every page.Switching that to (a) a count statement in SQL and (b) using a stored value refreshed once every 15 seconds, async, separate from page refresh. The the whole page load went after some time from SECONDS (2digits) to instant. DO not do stupid things like that and you should be fine.

The moment you are not fine anymore you may want to replace the disc with an SSD ;)

Upgrading to 2008 is always good. You really want to work on outdated tech? You also should make sure you run 64 bit - in case you ever put some real ram in you can just access it.